# find: missing argument to `-exec' when running from script file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, server

When I run the following command from my script file it gives me:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

But the same command from the command line works normally:

```
find /home/poseidoncharters/poseidon_backup/*.sql -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

I run the script like `./myscript.sh`

Comment: There is no obvious error here. Do you run the command exactly as visible here?

Comment: Use `-delete` instead of `-exec`

Comment: Debugging steps to try: (1) Run `type -a find` both at the command line and in the script, to see if you're calling the same `find` program both times. (2) Prepend `printf '<%s> '` to the command in the script, to see how the shell is expanding the command.

Comment: Check for DOS line endings; the last argument is probably `;\r`, not `;`.

Comment: Unrelated, but use `find /home/poseidoncharters/poseidon_backup -name '*.sql' ...` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well as other said on their comment command seems correct, and it was. the problem i was having was newline character problem, as i wrote this script in windows machine and then uploaded to unix server, so as soon as i ran `dos2unix remove_backup.sh` it started to work.

Comment: BTW, (1) this is the very first thing in the "before asking about problematic code" section of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info; (2) as a general practice consider using `bash -x yourscript` to trace the commands your script runs when debugging; in this case, you would see `$';\r'` instead of `\;` or `';'`, lett you know something's up.